# What is the probability of observing two 3s in a row before observing two dice which sum to 8?

Tags: probability

We observe an infinite sequence of dice rolls. What is the probability of observing two 3s in a row before observing two dice which sum to 8?

We have that $X_0, X_1, \cdots$ are i.i.d. uniform on $\{1, \cdots, 6\}$. I can write
$$T_A = \inf \{ n : X_{n-1} = X_n = 3\}\ \text{and}\ T_B = \inf \{ n : X_{n-1} + X_n = 8\}.$$

Now I want to calculate $P(T_A < T_B)$. Could I please have a hint about how to do this? Is the theory of martingales relevant here?

Comment: I suggest doing this by states, according to which values have been seen.

Comment: @lulu do you mean using a markov chain?

Comment: I think the language of states is easier to work with here, though it's same thing.  Note that you can simplify the matter if you notice some properties of the states.  For instance, tossing a $5$ before the first $3$ guarantees a loss.  And rolling a $2$ initially is the same as rolling a $4$ or a $6$.  And tossing a $1$ doesn't have any impact.  And so on.

Comment: Does the question intend to ask for two *consecutive* dice which sum to $8$?

Comment: Note:  if you meant that the throws that added to $8$ had to be consecutive, then my comment about $5$ is inaccurate, but the problem is then much simpler as a "state" now just consists of the last toss (and, again, $2,4,6$ are equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

"in a row" means consecutive.

Let us divide the throws into $4$ classes

- $s = Pr$ (start or $1$)
- $t = Pr$ (first $3$)
- $c = Pr(2,4,6),$ one step to $8$ other than $3$ and $5$
- $f = Pr(5)$

We can then frame step-by-step equations eg
from $s$, with one step we can

- return to $s$ with $Pr=\frac16$
- move to $t$ with $Pr=\frac16$
- move to $c$ with $Pr = \frac36$
- move to $f$ with $Pr = \frac16$

$s = \frac16s + \frac16 t + \frac36 c +\frac16 f$

$t=  \frac16 s + \frac16\times 1^@ +\frac36 c +\frac16\times 0^\$ \;\;$

[@: reached goal, won !]
[\$: we don't want to lose !]

$f = \frac16 s + \frac16 \times 0^\$ + \frac36 c +\frac16 f\;\;$

$c =  \frac16 s + \frac16 t + \frac26\times c +\frac16\times 0^\$+\frac16f\;\;$

Solving, we get
Pr(two successive $3's$ before a sum of eight from start)
$= s = \frac 7{47}$

Comment: You can't get from state $t$ to state $f$ in one step. This changes the calculations.

Comment: @paw88789: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but if I have just rolled a $3(t)$, why can't I roll a $5(f)$ on the next step ?

Comment: Because then you have sum of $8$. Game over.

Comment: @paw8879: How could I overlook that, thanks !

Comment: I did the same thing. But the answer disagreed both with a simulation and a matrix method...so I kept staring at it until...